# "initialising SSH storage failed" on bootstrap with manual provider

Tags: juju

I'm trying to use the manual provider to setup a juju environment on a remote server; when I try juju bootstrap I get:

> ERROR initialising SSH storage failed: failed to create storage dir: subprocess encountered error code 255 (Permission denied (publickey).)

I've generated my config per the docs for manual provider (https://jujucharms.com/docs/stable/clouds-manual) and I have ssh access on the machine in question (e.g. the private key I have is valid).

I have no idea what's blocking here; I get the same message running bootstrap verbosely.

Answer (score 0):

Enter the SSH config file:

```
# contents of $HOME/.ssh/config
Host juju-bootstrap
    HostName 1.2.3.4 # assuming that public ip address of the bootstrap-host is 1.2.3.4
    User uname # assuming that defined bootstrap-user is uname
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/yourprivateky
```

When using ssh Juju will honor the defined configuration and connect without a problem.

In addition you would need to add entry to /etc/hosts to enable Juju to communicate over http(s)

```
1.2.3.4   juju-bootstrap
```